# Find $A^\circ , \, cl (A),\, A', \partial A$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set 
$$Α=\left\{ \left(\dfrac 1 n, \dfrac 1m \right):\, n,m \in \mathbb N\right\}.$$

We want to find the sets $A^\circ=int\, A, \,cl(A) ,\, A' (\text {= derived set}) , \, \partial A  $. I followed  the definitions and I got:

> $$\begin{array}[t]{l}A^\circ= \emptyset\\
> cl( A)=A\cup\left\{\left(0,\dfrac 1m \right), \left(\dfrac 1 n,0\right): m,n \in \mathbb N \right\}\\
> A'=\left\{\left(0,\dfrac 1m \right), \left(\dfrac 1 n,0\right): m,n \in \mathbb N \right\}\\
> \partial A= cl(A)
> \end{array}
> $$

Is everything ok? I may have missed something.

**Edit:**  Our metric space is $(\mathbb R^2, e)$, where $e$ stands for the euclidean metric.

Comment: You're missing one point in the closure, and in $A'$. Boundary equals closure follows from empty interior, which is correct.

Comment: Ask yourself: is $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ actually closed?

Comment: I see... $(0,0)$!!

Comment: Yep, indeed you're right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be able to help